# Add and Remove Watermark to PDF using Python

Tags: python, pdf, watermark

Is there a way to add a watermark containing some images (icons, data matrix codes, preferred in a vector format) and text to a PDF in a way that the original appearance of the PDF can be restored, whenever needed?

In other words, I want to implement the following:
- add a watermark to existing PDF
- remove this watermark whenever desired

The watermark is provided by me in whichever format it might be needed to achieve my goal.

I have found implementations written in Python [like this solution using PyPDF2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50075979/watermark-two-pdfs-each-page-of-the-first-with-each-page-of-the-second#answer-50076049). But I have not found a way to remove the added watermark afterwards. Also I have found a solution to [add and remove watermarks using iText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44836260/itext-7-add-and-remove-watermark-on-a-pdf), which unfortunatelly is not a Python library.